# How to migrate Play Framework 1.x project to 2.0

Tags: jquery, playframework, fullcalendar, playframework-2.0

I am new to play technology. I was actually searching for a calender app developed on play and i got the source code of the calender from one of the website. The problem is that i am using play version 2.0 and the calender app was developed on play 1.x .

So can any one please help me in finding a way to migrate the project from play version 1.x to play 2.0  ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no migrate-automate, you need to rewrite this. On the other hand it's good opportunity to learn Play 2.0 - calendar app should be quite easy job especially with jQuery plugin such as FullCalendar.

**edit:** I published new version of FullCalendar implemaentation for Play 2.0 (Java) @ https://github.com/biesior/Play-20-Sample-FullCalendar-Java

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response .  can you just suggest me how to integrate a jquery fullcalender  plugin in play framework

Comment: Save and unzip jquery plugin in public directory, include it in layout template's header (see other parts that are included by default in main.scala.html) and that's all.

Of course you need to write some stuff in controller for storing/retriving data. It's best to go trough Play's website: 'Learn' section